# Dynamically change preferredContentSize?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to change the preferredContentSize of my Modal based on some settings.

For example: There is a switch, if the switch is off, i would like to hide some Cells. Thats fine, but i would also like to resize the modal.

Ill resize it normally with:

```
var contentSize = CGSizeMake(560, 562)

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.preferredContentSize = contentSize
}

@IBAction func photoSwitchPressed(sender: UISwitch) {
    if sender.on == true {
        photos = true
    } else {
       photos = false
        contentSize = CGSizeMake(560, 462) // resize?
        self.viewWillAppear(true) // how to force resize?
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the footerview of the tableView very small?

**Swift 3**

```
var contentSize = CGSize(width: 560, height: 562)
var photos = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    preferredContentSize = contentSize
}

@IBAction func photoSwitchPressed(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if sender.isOn == true {
        photos = true
    } else {
        photos = false
        contentSize = CGSize(width: 560, height: 462)

    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```